# output not providing accurate results python

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I am comparing a list with a list comprised of lists to find the most similar list and to use the string in the identified list in an if statement. I tried to compile the right code but it doesn't seem to provide me with the results i am looking for.

This is the code:

```
listA = [['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 423], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 430], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 398], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 507], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 392], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 169], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 149], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 397], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 387], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 448], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 433], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 355], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 477], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 484], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 520], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 500], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 167], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 373], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 328], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 557], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 203], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 519], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 15], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 498], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 481], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 359], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 414], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 510], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 403], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 360], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 494], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 374], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 149], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 131], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 326], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 179], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 530], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 163], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 338], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 427], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 422], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 134], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 443], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 386], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 144], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 356], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 513], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 497], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 424], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 200], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 369], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 149], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 492], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 164], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 413], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 144], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 399], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 16], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 385], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 28], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 406], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 393], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 156], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 157], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'down', 383], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 163], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 347], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 372], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 385], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 143], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 355], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 111], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 367], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 386], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 20], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 494], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 162], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 430], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 152], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 358], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'up', 393], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 357], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 28], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 134], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 179], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 22], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 377], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 146], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 158], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 134], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 407], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 167], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 154], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 190], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 184], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 354], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'down', 316], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 145], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'down', 367], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 170], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 175], ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'up', 410], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 304], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 166], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 27], ['1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 153], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 146], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 30], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 29], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', 'up', 163], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', 'up', 152], ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 30], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 38], ['1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', 'down', 157], ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 30], ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 13], ['0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', 'up', 176], ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'up', 24], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', 'down', 27], ['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 17], ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'up', 35], ['0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 21], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', 'down', 22], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'down', 20], ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'down', 1], ['1', '0', 'down', 1]]

listB = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0']


def fl(list1, list2):
    index = -1
    occ = 0
    for i, l in enumerate(list2):
        if l[:len(list1)] == list1:
            if l[-1] > occ:
                index = i
                occ = l[-1]
    if index == -1:
        return "The 1st list doesn't appear in the 2nd one."
    else:
        print(f"The 1st list appears in the 2nd one at index {index} with a number of occurrences equal to {occ}.")
        u = "up"
        y = "down"
        look_up = [(''.join(a[:6]), str(a[6])) if len(a) >= 7 else ('', '') for a in list2]

        if (''.join(list1), u) in look_up:
            print("up")

        elif (''.join(list1), y) in look_up:
            print("down")

print(fl(listB, listA))
```

This is the output:

```
The 1st list appears in the 2nd one at index 3 with a number of occurrences equal to 507.
up
None
```

The issue in this is that instead of `up` it should have written `down` because of the string element located in `listA` which is the similar list identified. I want it to be so that if the similar list identified in `listA` contains the string element `up` or `down`, the output must print the string element in accordance.

Please help, I'm still a novice.

Comment: Could you please minimize the input cases to just a few relevant ones; the current `listA` is far too large to be useful for trouble shooting.

Comment: Is 'up' or 'down' always at the last-but-one position in a list?

Comment: yes it is....also, for some reason when the input cases of listA are small (which is not what I'm aiming for) it seems to work, that is why I made it so long (which is not close too the length of what I'm using really)

Comment: Why are you making the list called `look_up`? It's looking for the list ending with 'up', which it's finding at `['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', 'up', 29]`, and then printing 'up' and that's it.

Comment: Are you assuming that the list values are unique? Because from what I see if the sublist `0,0,0,0,1,0` appears twice, one time with `down` and one time with `up` you will see printed `up`. Try to change the last `elif` to an `if`. I expect you will see both `up` and `down` then

Comment: BTW: I would simply do `list2[index][-2]` to get the matched `up`/`down`. No need to re-traverse the whole list when you already have the matching index...

Comment: another side quest if you don't mind...how can i make it so that i select the one with the most number of occurrences?

Answer (score 0):

You can use difflib.get_close_matches() to compare a list of lists against a singular list and get the most similar elements.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches